# Extract specific matching text (regex?) from YQL query

Tags: regex, yql

I would like to use YQL to extract textual Ids from particular paragraph divs on a webpage. The id is in the form "ApplicationRef:NNN". The basic query I use is along the lines of:

```
select content from html where url="..." and content matches "ApplicationRef*"
```

which returns the whole of the paragraph containing that text. However, I'd like to further process the result so that the query returns just the NNN part of each paragraph instead. Is this possible?

I realise that I can process the result from the YQL query further locally, but it would be neater if I can do all the processing in one go within the YQL query itself.

thanks,